# Jquery Get Response Data Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have this code that calls `buy.php` and makes a purchase and shows results.

`store.php`

```
<h4 class="result">Result:</h4>
function buy(id) {
      $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          URL: "buy.php?id="+id+"",
          success: function (data) {
              $(".result").html(data);
          }
      });


  }
```

`buy.php`

(after many check finally)

```
echo 'Purchase Successful!';
```

OR

```
    echo 'Purchase Failed!';
```

When `store.php` calls `buy.php` I do get

[image: Jquery Makes a get request]

This shows that Jquery do makes a get request not to `buy.php` but to the page itself (`store.php`) and when i call the buy function the content on the current page duplicates. Why its doing so? Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL option for `ajax` is `url`, not `URL`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

```
function buy(id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "buy.php?id="+id+"",
// Here ^
        success: function (data) {
            $(".result").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

---

Side note: If `id` is a number, your code will work, but there's a better way to supply the `id` value: Using the `data` option:

```
function buy(id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "buy.php",             // <== change is here
        data: {id: id},             // <== and here
        success: function (data) {
            $(".result").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The nice thing about using the `data` option (with an object, as above) is that jQuery will ensure that the parameters are correctly URI-encoded. Again, doesn't matter for a number (if `id` is a number), but it's a good habit to get into, because it matters quite a lot for strings.

Comment: @AsheshKumar before posting question you need to some R&D for your question it's many time asking question so may be downvote why

Comment: Sorry, to say but i don't understand your english.

Comment: @AsheshKumar: Basically he's saying: Step 1 is to look at the documentation and examples for what you're using. In this case, you might have seen that it was `url` instead of `URL`. Of course, if you didn't know JavaScript was case-sensitive, you might not have noticed even looking at the docs.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't know that Jquery was case sensitive , So why downvote? I stared Jquery Today!

Comment: @AsheshKumar: **Again**: Never assume you know who downvoted anything. Separately, complaining about downvotes is never constructive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **URL** to **url** and send parameter to data and try with `full url` of file

```
function buy(id) {
      $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: "http://localhost/html/home/buy.php",//change according file location
          data:{'id':id},
          success: function (data) {
              $(".result").html(data);
          }
      });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The option method should be type and your URL needs to be url.

```
<h4 class="result">Result:</h4>
function buy(id) {
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "buy.php?id="+id+"",
          success: function (data) {
              $(".result").html(data);
          }
      });


  }
```